# What causes arbitrary Tailwind CSS values to not work when styling a React color component?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am creating an application with react and tailwind css, where given a color or word a color is returned in hexadecimal, but when I try to style the color with arbitrary tailwind values, they don't work.
I have 2 components, WordForm and ColorSquare
WordForm.jsx

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import { createPaleteWord } from "../api/color.api";
import ColorSquare from "../components/ColorSquare";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

function WordForm() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm();
  const [color, setColor] = useState([]);

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    const response = await createPaleteWord(data);
    setColor(response.data);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type a word"
          {...register("word", { required: true })}
        />
        {errors.word && toast.error("Type a word")}
        <button>Create Palette</button>
      </form>

      {color && color.map((e) => <ColorSquare color={e} key={e} />)}
    </>
  );
}

export default WordForm;
```

The classes that this component has are:bg-[#4A6A9F] w-full h-9 underline
ColorSquare.jsx:

```
function ColorSquare({ color }) {
  const styles = `bg-[${color}] w-full h-9 underline`;
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={styles}>{color}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default ColorSquare;
```

I already checked if the color property is a string and indeed, it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem using inline styles like:

**style={{backgroundColor: color}}**